# WSDL importer generates faulty server

Tags: delphi, soap, wsdl, delphi-2007

I've been trying to get a soap server up that implements (is that the correct term?) a wsdl specification made by a third party. I have used Delphi's wsdl importer. (Part of) the generated code looks like this:

```
miniPortType = interface(IInvokable)
['{824D172A-9C1F-D202-5B21-4C324553BCF0}']

  // Cannot unwrap: 
  // - Input element wrapper name does not match operation's name
  function miniService(const aMessage: MiniMessageType): MiniAnswerType; stdcall;
end;
```

When called, the server says that "*No method named 'MiniMessageType' is supported by interface 'miniPortType'*".

I can only get this to work by making the name of the function and name of the main element of the message the same.

I think it should be possible to have different names. At least soapUI doesn't complain. And I actually have no choice but to implement the wsdl as is. Does anybody know how I can work around this?

I'm using Delphi 2007.

Thanks, Miel.

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: So what did you end up doing?  I was hoping to find a useful solution here.

Comment: @chris I gave up trying to write SOAP services in Delphi. I find the lack of support for SOAP in Delphi disturbing. Especially for services. I now write those in C#. The official Embarcadero stance seems to be that services should be written in Prism...

Comment: sad news indeed. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Lacking the original WSDL, but having bumped into a similar thing, I think this is document-literal versus rpc-encoded: server side still does not support document-literal.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, the SOAP interface is actually defined in a "table" at the bottom of the definitions, and it is this which is used to do the conversion between Delphi types and SOAP types in the communications. I've "corrected" this sort of thing in the past by manually changing the table building calls, but you have to be careful, and may also need to mangle the SOAP text at the appropriate point to make it all fit.

Comment: I had a similar issue. The newest wsdlimp couldn't generate fields for the soap headers. However fields'classes for headers were generated. So in order to run the method I had to by hand instantiate all headers and send one by one before method execution. RIO.SoapHeader.Send(); I hope that it will help someone.

Comment: @John client side, that is indeed the way to go. See for instance Jean-Marie Babet in these messages https://www.codenewsfast.com/cnf/article/752817581/permalink.art-ng1920q1653 and https://www.codenewsfast.com/cnf/article/752817581/permalink.art-ng1920q1665 and the docs at http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/devwin32/soapdefiningandusingsoapheaders_xml.html